# Multiple projects using ASP.NET MVC areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

How can I setup multiple projects using areas in asp.net mvc 2?

Comment: I did't need to do anything, just registering my area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't need to do anything, just registering my area.